# Java Trying to sample data every 10 seconds

Tags: java

I would like to sample data I get from a API call on a even 10 seconds.  Now I call the api, update the data and wait for 10 seconds, but this is ten seconds plus the time it takes the code to execute.  Is there a way to figure out how much to pause so that the pause would be 10 seconds-the time it took to sample the data????

code:

```
do{
  // sample data
    for(int i=0; i<cMarkets.mTitle.length;  i++ )
        {
            mBitTrex.market=i;
            cTicker prices = new cTicker(); 
            prices=mBitTrex.GetCurSales();

            String FileName = "graph"+cMarkets.mTitle[i];
            FileName+=".txt";
            FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter( FileName,true);
            BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);

            String say;
            say=Double.toString(prices.last)+","+Double.toString(prices.bid)+","+Double.toString(prices.ask);

            bufferWritter.write(say );
            bufferWritter.write("\r" );
            bufferWritter.write("\n" );
            System.out.println(say);


            bufferWritter.close();
        }
// wait for 10 seconds then sample data again
// how can I make it so the puse is 10 seconds-the time it took to sample the fdata??
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        } while(System.in.available()==0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`java.util.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) with its [`scheduleAtFixedRate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)) method.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your logic here
    }
}, 0, 10000);
```

The javadoc is a little obtuse, but basically fixed-rate scheduling works like a constant ticker that will execute your task on every tick.

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` will get you a time in milliseconds. The absolute value of this when the code starts minus this when it ends is the number of milliseconds it took to run the code.

Example:

```
int time1=System.currentTimeMillis();

// run some code...

int millisecondsToCompleteCode=System.currentTimeMillis()-time1;
```

Comment: Why do you need the `Math.abs()`? You could just do `int millisecondsToCompleteCode = System.currentTimeMillis() - time1;`, right?

Comment: IIRC it can count up or down, depending on your JVM.

Comment: You're arguing that some JVMs go back in time? I will definitely upvote your answer if you can provide documentation for that.

Comment: Maybe I was thinking of `nanoTime()`. You're correct, it is the actual milliseconds time. I will update the answer.